# Spring Boot - fetching data from another microservice

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

I am using Spring Boot for my API. I am rewriting my API, to adopt the microservices architecture.

I have 2 classes:

**1) Product**

**2) Ingredient**

My Code:

Here is my **Product** class:

```
    public class Product{
       private String name;
       @ElementCollection
       private List<Long> productIngredients = new ArrayList<>(); //Ingredient
       private Double quantity = 0.0;
       private Double productCost = 0.0;
}
```

Here is my **Ingredient** class:

```
public class Ingredient{    
     private String name;
     private String unit;
     private Double quantity = 0.0;
}
```

In the **Product** microservice, I am doing an API call to the **Ingredient** microservice:

```
// Making a call to the Ingredients microservice from the product microservice

WebClient myWebClient = WebClient.create("http://localhost:8090/api");

@GetMapping("/ingredients/get")
public Flux<Product> getIngredients(){
   
        return myWebClient
                .get()
                .uri("/ingredients/ingredient/list")
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToFlux(Product.class);
}
```

However, the above getIngredients() method is not working.

**My Question:**

I want to fetch data from the Ingredient microservice, however, I get the following error:

> "error": "Internal Server Error",
> "trace": "org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClientRequestException: Connection refused: no further information: localhost/127.0.0.1:80; nested exception is io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connection refused: no further information: localhost/127.0.0.1:80\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.ExchangeFunctions$DefaultExchangeFunction.lambda$wrapException$9(ExchangeFunctions.java:141)\r\n\tSuppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException: \nError has been observed at the following site(s):\n\t|_ checkpoint ⇢ Request to GET http://localhost/api/components/component/list [DefaultWebClient]\nStack trace:\r\n\t\tat org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Connection refused: no further information: localhost/127.0.0.1:80`, exception says that:

1. there's nothing listening on port 80 on your local machine
2. you're making a request to localhost:80 not localhost:8090, are you sure `myWebClient` instance is the one that is configured with the correct URL?